# URL rewrite double appending question mark

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have the two rules:

```
<rewrite url="^/de(/.+)(\?(.+))?$" to="$1?lang=de&amp;$3" />
<rewrite url="^/terms-and-conditions(\?(.+))?$" to="~/Pages/Terms.aspx?$2" processing="stop"/>
```

This should make:

```
/terms-and-conditions
/de/terms-and-conditions
```

All point to the same page (`Terms.aspx`)

This works in all test cases, except for a URL starting with `/de` and has a querystring.

```
/de/terms-and-conditions?x=y
```

Gives the querystring:

```
?x=y?lang=de&
```

How can I fix this rule to have an ampersand and not a second question mark?

I can get it to work by breaking it into two rules:

```
<rewrite url="^/de(/.+)\?(.*)$" to="$1?lang=de&amp;$2" />
<rewrite url="^/de(/.+)$" to="$1?lang=de" />
```

But for simplicities sake I'd like this in a single rule!

Comment: Try `^\/de(\/[^?]+)(\?(.+))?$`.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\/de(\/[^?]+)(\?(.+))?$
```

It words because `(\/[^?]+)` (matching `/` and then 1 or more characters other then `/`) restricts the regex to match just 1 subpart between `/`s, and `(\?(.+))?` matches *optionally* (due to the final `?`) a literal `?` and then any number of characters other than a newline.